# Proper way to set background image for a layout android

Tags: android, image, android-glide

I have tried many possible ways to set a perfect background image for a layout but never got a perfect result. Let me describe you my problem. I have an image of size `2880 x 5120` pixels. I have kept the image in the `xxxhdpi` folder and then loading the image using `Glide` library as the background image. I am resizing the image by calculating the screen size programmatically.
Here is my following code to load image as the background image.

```
Glide.with(LoginActivity.this)
                    .load(R.drawable.login_background)
                    .override(screenSize[0]*2,screenSize[1])
                    .animate(animationObject)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
                    .into(backgroundImage);
```

`screenSize()` method:

```
private int[] screenSize() {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        return new int[]{size.x, size.y};
    }
```

This is the actual background image:

[image]

After loading the image as the background image. I am getting the below result.

[image]

The image is not completely fitting the screen. 
**What can be the best optimal solution to set a background image ?**

Comment: Use can use .fitCenter() or .centerCrop()

Comment: same result as above. didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You need not go through this trouble of calculating different screen size. You should use different size image resources and android will handle it as per the screen size. You can use [this post](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/App-Splash-Screen-Sizes) to read more but I have summarized sizes you can use in your project for the background image.

It has all the sizes you need to use for different screens as well as landscape mode sizes are mentioned.

```
MDPI:
Portrait: 320x480px
Landscape: 480x320px
HDPI:
Portrait: 480x800px
Landscape: 800x480px
XHDPI:
Portrait: 720px1280px
Landscape: 1280x720px
XXHDPI:
Portrait: 960px1600px
Landscape: 1600x960px
XXXHDPI:
Portrait: 1280px1920px
Landscape: 1920x1280px
```

Comment: wont it increase the apk size ?

Comment: Perhaps, but this isnt the excuse not to use different size images to fit your needs, this is google recommended solution to include all size to fit the need. Plus there are other ways to reduce APK size caused by accessive code calculations..

Comment: dont you think these resolutions are little old. I mean if you look at LG G3 resolution. Its `1440x2960`. How to deal with that ?

Comment: you cancheck on android developer docs and read logic behind this to understand..

Comment: link please @Aalap